# Mongoose populate denormalized data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a `User` model and a `Book` model. I want some data from my books to be denormalized on each `User` document, but still have the option to populate if needed. If I set `ref: 'Book'` on the `books.$._id` it gets populated inside the `_id` path which is unintended. I would like the population to overwrite the denormalized data.

How do I accomplish this?

*in* ***users.model.js***:

```
const { Schema } = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    books: {
        type: [
            {
                _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                title: String,
                length: Number,
            },
        ],
        default: [],
    },
});
```

**Desired outcome**

*in* ***users.controller.js***:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const users = await User.find({})
    /*
    users: [{
        _id: ObjectId(),
        name: 'Andrew',
        books: [{
            _id: ObjectId(),
            title: 'Game of Thrones',
            length: 298,
        }, { ... }],
    }, { ... }]
    */
});

app.get('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    const book_id = req.params.id;
    const user = await User.findById(book_id).populate({
        path: 'books',
        model: 'Book',
    });
    /*
    user: {
        _id: ObjectId(),
        name: 'Andrew',
        books: [{
            _id: ObjectId(),
            name: 'Game of Thrones',
            length: 298,
            author: 'Simone Dunow',
            releasedOn: Date(),
            price: 30,
            ...
        }, { ... }],
    }
    */
});
```

Schemas I've tried so far:

```
    books: {
        type: [
            {
                _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                title: String,
                length: Number,
            },
        ],
        default: [],
        ref: 'Book',
    },
```

*returns array of `{ _id: null }`*

```
    books: {
        type: [
            {
                _id: {
                    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'Book',
                },
                title: String,
                length: Number,
            },
        ],
        default: [],
    },
```

*books are populated inside of `_id`: `{ _id: { Book } }`*

```
    books: {
        type: [
            {
                type: {
                    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    title: String,
                    length: Number,
                },
                ref: 'Book',
            },
        ],
        default: [],
    },
```

*throws exception: invalid type*

Answer (score 0):

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    books: [{
        id: { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Book'} //Whatever string you have used while modeling your schema
        title: String,
        length: Number,
    }],
});
```

While using the schema you can populate as follows :

```
populate({ path: 'books.id' })
```

Output :

```
{ 
    _id : // someid
    name : "somename"
    books : [
        { 
          id : {//document referring to Books collection},
          title : "sometitle",
          length : //somelength
        }, ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, but is that conventional? Isn't it a bit awkward to have the document inside of `id`?

Comment: Name it whatever you want instead of id. Yes it happens that way itself. Also it is conventional

Comment: In mongoose populate means set the field, to the document you are referencing. As id field refers to Book the id field when populated will have a Book document in it.

Answer (score 0):

To anybody that might be still looking to achieve a full replacement, full disclosure: It might be a bit hacky for some evangelists or even have a performance toll on high traffic apps, but if you really want to do it, you can tap into the toJSON method of the schema like the following:

```
UserSchema.method('toJSON', function () {
  let obj = this.toObject();
  obj.books = obj.books.map(
    (book) => (Schema.Types.ObjectId.isValid(book.id)) ? book : book.id
  );
  return obj;
});
```

What's going on here is basically we're replacing the whole property with the populated result when the book.id has been populated otherwise we just return the original object by checking the validity of the book's id (when populated will be a full bloomed object rather than an id).